# How can I copy the contents of a file directly into my Windows clipboard when I'm running the command on a remote Linux machine via ssh in Git Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, clipboard, xclip

I'm using Windows 10. I open Git Bash and then ssh into an Ubuntu server. Often I want to copy the whole contents of a large text file.

Rather than using scp to download the file to my Windows machine, I sometimes would rather quickly copy the contents to my clipboard.

Using `cat` and then scrolling thousands of lines and then manually copying to clipboard is possible but isn't practical.

I'd rather pipe `cat` to a command that copies the output to my Windows clipboard. Or call some other command like `xclip`.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211817/copy-the-contents-of-a-file-into-the-clipboard-without-displaying-its-contents and [How can I copy the output of a command directly into my clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard) are similar questions, but `xclip` causes this error:

```
xclip -sel c < /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

**Update after [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117294/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-file-directly-into-my-windows-clipboard-when-i?noredirect=1#comment106326809_60117294):**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39556508/470749 was interesting, but `X11Forwarding yes` is already in my server config, and when I prepended `ForwardX11 yes` to `~/.ssh/config` and then ran `ssh -v -X -t -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myuser@■■.■■■.■■■.■■`, I still got:

```
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

and then when I ran `xsel -b < /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`:

```
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Maybe [X session in Git Bash on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10129267/470749) will help me further.

Comment: Does this help [Error: Can't open display: (null) when using Xclip to copy ssh public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18695934/5291015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need and X server on your Windows host and X-tunnelling in your ssh connection. `xclip` will send the clipboard to your X server, and the server will provide it to Windows.

1. Install an X server to your Windows machine. I use VcXsrv, there are XMing and others. The flavor of X is not important.
2. Launch the server
3. in Git Bash use command `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`
4. Make sure that `/etc/ssh/sshd.config` on the remote node has line `X11Forwarding yes`
5. enable X11 tunneling in ssh command: add `-Y` flag to `ssh`: `ssh -Y <server_address>`

While there are some recipies on Stack Overflow already, there is one glitch. Note `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`. If you omit `localhost`, that is `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, then `xclip` will fail on the remote node :

`connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0`

Comment: Thanks for these steps. I haven't tried them yet, but they sound like they're probably correct, so I've accepted the answer.

Comment: They do work. I tested on my windows 10 - Ubuntu 18.04 pair. Copied 1 Mb log file over the clipboard.